# How to download python packages using Conda and later install offline?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pypi

I know through pip I can download Python packages using the below command. But "pip install" is breaking my internal package dependencies.

When I do:

```
pip download <package-name> -d <download-path>
```

This is supposed to download packages along with their dependencies.

I tried and failed to find this feature for Conda.

Please let me know if there's a way to download python packages along with their dependencies through conda and install the latter offline in the virtual environment.

I need this method because our client restricted access to Pypi and the Anaconda repository.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for the `--download-only` flag. From `conda install --help`:

```
--download-only       Solve an environment and ensure package caches are
                      populated, but exit prior to unlinking and linking
                      packages into the prefix.
```

The "*solve and environment*" part indicates that it will include all dependencies.

The `--offline` flag could also be helpful for the latter time when you try installing. This will force Conda to attempt to use only the cached packages to satisfy package specifications.

Comment: I did below steps. Lets say for python package spacy. (1)set CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=<location where I want to download package> (2)conda install -c conda-forge spacy --download-only --> it will download to folder set in CONDA_PKGS_DIRS. (3) conda install --offline spacy. This will install from the package present in CONDA_PKGS_DIRS. We can change also CONDA_PKGS_DIRS if we are moving the location of installation.