# How to download a full package dependency chain using conda?

Tags: python, package, conda

I have a requirements file that describes the conda packages I need. These are required dependencies in a script I want to run. The script needs to run on a machine that is not connected to a network or internet. Therefore, I have decided to use `download-only` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62668915/1987258).

This is not working for me. When I choose just one dependency to download, I get an error. This is my command-line statement:

`conda install --download-only grpcio=1.35.0`

This is the error I get:

> CondaExitZero: Package caches prepared. UnlinkLinkTransaction
> cancelled with --download-only option

Apparently, the `download-only` is in this cases helps me to cancel the download.... That is not what I want. I want to download the full dependency chain in order to use it in an offline environment.

How do I do that?

Comment: Having a second look at this, are you sure it didn't download? I.e., check your package cache for the `tar.gz` file? Or is the issue that the dependencies aren't also downloaded? If the latter is the case, then the linked answer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Please file a bug report on [the Conda repository](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues), since this appears that it shouldn't be happening. I suspect the issue is that for download-only transactions, Conda still determines that a package might need to be removed in order to *eventually* install the requested package. That shouldn't be necessary, so I'd call that a bug.

In the meantime, either try creating a new environment and then using the `--download-only` flag with that environment activated. Alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210871/570918) shows how to download raw packages for a full solve, ignoring any existing package cache.

Comment: Done https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11458